# reverse method - 1.9.1 v 1.8.7

Tags: ruby

I wrote some code:

`output = File.open(text_file).collect.reverse.join("<BR>")`

It seems to work okay on 1.8.7 but throws the error

`NoMethodError - undefined method 'reverse' for #<Enumerator: #<File:C:\EduTester\cron\rufus.log>:collect>:`

on 1.9.1 (ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32])

Does somebody know **why** this happens and **how** to fix this?  (Why is of most interest to me.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First how to fix it - you should be doing this:

```
output = File.open(text_file).to_a.reverse.join("<BR>")
```

This will work on either version of Ruby. Basically you need to turn the file into an array of lines (with `.to_a`) before reversing them and adding line breaks.

In terms of the why (this gets a little technical): `File` mixes in the `Enumerable` module, which gives it methods like `collect`. Now in Ruby 1.87, if you called `Enumberable.collect` without a block it would return an `Array`. But in 1.9, it returns an `Enumerator` - which doesn't respond to the `reverse` method.

Here are the 2 versions of the method in question:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect
http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect

So basically before 1.9 `.collect` was a (hacky) equivalent to `.to_a`. But always use `.to_a` to turn something into an array.

Comment: Perfect, works smoothly now. Thank you for the explanation. I found that 1.9.1 enumerable doesn't support reverse but I din't make the last step to collect and put everything together. Well, next time I know what to look for.

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby 1.8.7 if a block is given or not given with collect method, it returns an array.
But in 1.9 , it will only return array if block is given with collect method. Otherwise it will return enumerator object.
From [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) -

*Collect method-*

*Returns a new array with the results of running block once for every element in enum.
If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.*

Answer (score 2):

in 1.8.7, the **collect** method returns an **array** when applied on a File object whereas in 1.9.3, it returns an **enumerator**. **reverse** method can be applied on an array only.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this works in 1.8.7 is that when you call [`Enumerable#collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) without a block in 1.8.7, it uses a default block which just returns its arg, so `file.collect` is equivalent to `file.collect {|x| x}` which returns an array of the lines in the file, on which in you can call [Array#reverse`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-reverse).

In 1.9.x, calling [`Enumerable#collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) without a block returns an [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html). Enumerator does not natively support `#reverse`, nor does its mixin [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html). So, you get NoMethodError.

If you want to write this expression in a way compatible with either version, use `#to_a` instead of `#collect`.

`output = File.open(text_file).to_a.reverse.join("<BR>")`